# How to repeatedly define arrays with numbered names in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a for loop that defines arrays repeatedly, but with different array name each loop.
For example:

```
for i = 1 to 10
   dim array"i"(1 to 5) as long
loop
```

Here, I don't know how to convert "i" to 1,2,3....10, so that there would be array1,array2,array3....array10. Any ideas on how this could work?

Comment: You can't. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: List of arrays would be probably the best solution.

Comment: Why not a 2 dimensional array? `Dim Arr(1 to 10, 1 to 5)`  Then you can call it `Arr(2,4)` which returns the 4th item in the 2nd array.

Comment: Good point @Scott Craner, I will try it out, thanks!

Comment: Or even a collection of arrays, depending on what you want to do with the arrays.

Comment: Posted a late answer demonstrating how to handle a *List of arrays* (following @Vityata 's suggestion) together with some test data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Array of Arrays**

Possibly it comes close to your needs to create a *List of Arrays* (aka *Jagged Array* or *Array of Arrays*) as proposed by Vityata and execute a sub call to redimension any "sub" array.

```
    For idx = 1 To 10               ' << example loop from idx = 1 to n
        Standardize a(idx), 1, 5    ' << sub call redimension e.g. from 1 to 5
    Next idx
```

**Main procedure including test displays of some array items**

Note: assigned some numeric and alphabetic test values, reduced number of sub arrays and loops and used constants to reference sub arrays (e.g. via `a(NUMS)` and `a(ALPHA)`); an individual item, e.g. `a(ALPHA)(5)` thus would return a string value of "five" (note the special syntax!).

```
Sub ArrayOfArrays()
  ' [0] provide for a variant container array
    Dim a()
  ' [1] fill container with empty "sub" arrays
  '      (note that first sub array remains empty just to allow 1-based enumeration)
    a = Array(Array(), Array(), Array())
  ' [2] assign values to variant "sub" arrays - temporarily zero-based
  '     (note that at this point you are assigning arrays of different lengths)
    Const NUMS& = 1, ALPHA& = 2       ' << change to your needs
    a(NUMS) = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)       ' << test items
    a(ALPHA) = Array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six")

  ' [3] >> standardize all "sub" arrays to the same boundaries 1 To 6 in a loop
  '     (note that you'd change here from 0-based to 1-based "sub" arrays)
    Dim idx&
    For idx = NUMS To ALPHA         ' << example loop from idx = 1 to 2
        Standardize a(idx), 1, 6    ' << sub call redimension from 1 to 6
    Next idx

  ' ================= Some display examples ===============================
  ' [4a] display some test items from NUMS and ALPHA (including empty ones)
  '     (note the differing syntax)
    Debug.Print "* [4a] Display test items:"

    Debug.Print "* NUMS - " & UBound(a(NUMS)) & " items: ", _
                Join(a(NUMS), ",")
    Debug.Print "  e.g. a(NUMS)(1) =" & a(NUMS)(1)   '--> 1
    Debug.Print "  e.g. a(NUMS)(2) =" & a(NUMS)(2)   '--> 2

    Debug.Print "* ALPHA - " & UBound(a(ALPHA)) & " items: ", _
                Join(a(ALPHA), ",")
    Debug.Print "  e.g. a(ALPHA)(5) =" & a(ALPHA)(5) '--> "five"
    Debug.Print "  e.g. a(ALPHA)(6) =" & a(ALPHA)(6) '--> "six"

  ' [4b] display each first and last item of each category
    Debug.Print "* [4b] Display first and last item of each category:"
    Dim i&, first&, last&, categories$
    categories = "Dummy,Nums,Alpha"
    For i = NUMS To ALPHA
        first = LBound(a(i)): last = UBound(a(i))   ' 1 to 6
        Debug.Print "  " & Split(categories, ",")(i) & ": " & vbTab & _
                    "1st item: |" & a(i)(first) & "|," & vbTab & _
                    "last item: |" & a(i)(last) & "|"
    Next i

End Sub
```

**Sub call `Standardize`**

```
Sub Standardize(arr, lowerBoundary&, upperBoundary&)
' Purpose: change jagged array boundaries by preserving included items
' Note:    argument arr is passed ByRef (by default)
    Dim tmpArr
    tmpArr = arr
    ReDim Preserve tmpArr(lowerBoundary To upperBoundary)
    arr = tmpArr
End Sub
```

**Test displays in Immediate Window of VBEditor**

```
* [4a] Display test items:
* NUMS - 6 items:           1,2,3,4,,
  e.g. a(NUMS)(1) =1
  e.g. a(NUMS)(2) =2
* ALPHA - 6 items:          one,two,three,four,five,six
  e.g. a(ALPHA)(5) =five
  e.g. a(ALPHA)(6) =six
* [4b] Display first and last item of each category:
  Nums:     1st item: |1|,  last item: ||
  Alpha:    1st item: |one|,    last item: |six|
```